# Delve- How to turn off "show documents" option at tenant level

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, delve

We recently enabled Delve globally, but we want to disable some of the features in Delve and our main concern is "Documents".

We want to disable it at tenant level so that individual users cannot view files/documents of other users in "Delve".

We can achieve this individually at their respective profile but is there a way that we can achieve this globally?

Comment: I have this same question. I understand that the documents are still shared and can be found. But there are many instances when a user may put a document in a location where he/she thinks only a certain user has access to, but in reality, it may be open to others. And the scenario is that another user looks at the original person's Delve and realizes they have access to all these documents they didnt know about.
Eg a non tech savvy VP of Finance thinks he is sharing files with only his team but he is putting the document in a folder that is accessible by all others.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some confusion about [what Delve is](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-Office-Delve-1315665a-c6af-4409-a28d-49f8916878ca?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1). Delve tries to figure out what documents are important to you (the viewing user) and displays them to you. This means that what you see in Delve will be different from what others see. It also respects permissions on files. From *[Are my documents safe in Office Delve?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Are-my-documents-safe-in-Office-Delve-f5f409a2-37ed-4452-8f61-681e5e1836f3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)*:

> Delve never changes any permissions. Only **you** can see your private
>   documents in Delve.
>
> Also, other people can't see your private activities, such as what
>   documents you've read, what emails you've sent and received, or what
>   Skype for Business conversations you've been in. Other people can see
>   that you've modified a document, but only if they have access to the
>   same document.
>
> What you see in Delve is different from what other people see. **You** can
>   see your private documents and other documents that you have access
>   to. **Other people** can see their documents and documents that they have
>   access to.

While you might be able to hide documents from the Delve view, they are still accessible to you either through group membership or explicit sharing.

To completely remove them would require that you disallow all sharing from a user's OneDrive for Business site and revoke any currently shared documents. If you have sharing concerns, you might want to consider [disabling external sharing](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-external-sharing-for-your-SharePoint-Online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85) or [limit sharing to specific domains](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Restricted-domains-sharing-in-SharePoint-Online-and-OneDrive-for-Business-5d7589cd-0997-4a00-a2ba-2320ec49c4e9).

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to review the option of disabling Office Graph in your tenant, which plays a pivotal role in how user information is displayed in Delve, including documents that users have interacted with and used. It has broader impacts, however, across your tenant, such as removing Delve from the App Launcher as well. So be sure to weigh the costs before exploring this option. It would, overall, help you achieve the user experience that you're seeking though. Here are a few applicable articles to reference:

1. [Overview of Office Graph and how to manage it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/delve-for-office-365-admins)
2. [Impacts of disabling or enabling Office Graph](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/delve-for-office-365-admins#BKMK_EffectOfficegraphOnOff)